# jQuery UI Icons appearing in jQuery Autocomplete results

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I am using the [jQuery Autocomplete Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)  (by Jörn Zaefferer of jQuery fame).

BackEnd Code:

```
public JsonResult GetCompanyNames()
    {
        return Json(Model.CompanyNames); //returns valid JSon
    }
```

Relevant JS Code:

```
$('#CompanyName').autocomplete(['Suzuki', 'Honda', 'blah']); //This works fine
$('#CompanyName').autocomplete('/Account/Login/GetCompanyNames'); //This renders icons!
```

While passing a Javascript Array as url/data parameter it works fine as predicted.

But when I passed a `Area/Controller/Action` as parameter it shows me jQuery's ui-icons (huh?) in the corresponding textbox!!?

Yes, I wish I could attach a screenshot. Trust me, I still can't believe my eyes either.

While debugging, I have verified that my method returns valid `JsonResult` data. I'm using using: ASP.NET MVC3, jQuery 1.4.2. I have checked and found the same behaviour across Chrome 6.0, IE8 and and Firefox 3.5

UPDATE : The icons appear even before the autocomplete request returns from the server.

Comment: Why are you using the bassistance.de plugin if you're already using jQuery UI? That plugin was deprecated in favor of the jQuery UI version.

Comment: I upgraded to jQuery UI's autocomplete.(Although not without difficulty, it was worth it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to allow GET requests:

```
public ActionResult GetCompanyNames()
{
    return Json(Model.CompanyNames, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Another tip: Use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see what's exactly being exchanged between the client and server and any possible error messages.

---

UPDATE:

The problem comes from the fact that you need to manually parse the JSON by using the `parse` and `formatItem` functions because the plugin expects the data to be formatted in a special way:

```
$('#CompanyName').autocomplete('/Account/Login/GetCompanyNames', {
    dataType: 'json',
    formatItem: function (data, i, max, value, term) {
        return value;
    },
    parse: function (data) {
        return $.map(data, function (item) {
            return { data: item, value: item, result: item };
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @Darin: I did try the above, still doesn't work. The console shows me this error message : "Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'split'."

Comment: What does FireBug says? Is the request sent to the server? What does the server respond? Are you returning the exact same JSON array: `['Suzuki', 'Honda', 'blah']` from your controller action or is it some complex objects? Your controller action should return like this: `return Json(new[] { "Suzuki", "Honda", "blah" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. You see: a string array. Is `Model.CompanyNames` a `string[]`?

Comment: Yes, Request is sent to the server. Server response is as predicted. ie. Model.CompanyNames is a string[].  Firebug's console gives me no warnings/errors. Response header contains Content-Type : application/json; charset=utf-8  Status : 200 OK

Comment: Try specifying JSON: `$('#CompanyName').autocomplete('/Account/Login/GetCompanyNames', { dataType: 'json' });`

Comment: Yes, This was my first reaction and I have specified and still got no results.  Which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Also, I have specified the datatype for the $('#CompanyName').result(); Is that equivalent? Or do i need to do it for the call to autocomplete()?

Comment: @conqenator, you need to use the `parse` function along with `formatItem`. Please see my update.

Comment: Worked absolutely fine with [Jquery UI's Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp). (Sigh of relief)